# How to know the if some combination repeats using matlab

Tags: matlab, repeat

Please allow me to post this admin:

ok so this is my problem, i want to generate all combination of a, and b, for example 1 and 2, having a combinations of (1,2), (2,1),(-1,2), and (2,-1), so 4 combination, but i want only one combination as representative of all 4 combination to be display in output for example only (1,2). so this is my draft code:

```
fprintf(' a b z \n _ _ _ \n');
for a= -1:3
    for b=-1:3
        z=a^2 + b^2

    end
end

ctr=1;
i(:,3) %the position of z in array
for x =1:length(z) %the length of z array 
    if z = i(1,1)
        ctr = ctr +1;
    else
        fprintf(' %d %d %d\n',a,b,z);
    end
end
```

so this the output i want:

```
 a b    z   no. of repetitions
 1 1    2   4
 1 0    1   4
 1 2    5   4
 1 3    10  4
 0 2    4   2
 0 3    9   2
 2 2    8   1
 2 3    13  2
 3 3    18  1
 0 0    0   1
```

no. of repetition means how many possible combination of a and b can generate

Comment: Do you summarize these four combinations because they contain the same absolute numbers or because they result in the same `z`? To ask this in another way: Assume your input is -1:5, would (3,4) and (0,5) share the same group?

Comment: no sir,  it's all about the combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
in=-1:3
%calculate z
[a,b]=meshgrid(in);
z=a.^2+b.^2;
%sort absolute values ascending, which allows to use unique
ac=sort(abs([a(:) b(:)]),2);
%use unique to identify duplicates
[f,g,h]=unique(ac,'rows');
%count
cnt=histc(h,1:max(h));
disp([a(g),b(g),z(g),cnt])
```

The output is:

```
0    0    0    1
1    0    1    4
2    0    4    2
3    0    9    2
1    1    2    4
2    1    5    4
3    1   10    4
2    2    8    1
3    2   13    2
3    3   18    1
```

Comment: i tried your code and this give an error: Undefined function or variable 'in'.

Error in me (line 2)
[a,b]=meshgrid(in);

Comment: Added the missing line.

Comment: it generate some combinations, but didn't display my desired output

Comment: Besides ordering I don't see any difference

Comment: i'm only expecting positive combination,but the output shows some negative and positive combination

Comment: I added the output I get running the code, I don't see any negative combinations.